# JavaScript arrays with functions

Tags: javascript

Planned output:

```
The array has 10 elements.
The average of the values is 36.1
```

I plan two functions: addNumber() and printInfo().

Function: addNumber() reads a value from a text input field on the HTML document (id="num") and adds it at the end of the array.

Another function: printInfo() outputs the amount of elements in the array to the console, then the average of their values.

HTML document has two buttons for calling the functions.

I wrote:

```
let arr = [];
arr.push (function addNumber() {
let element = document.getElementById("num");
})
function printInfo() {
console.log (arr.length );
}
```

How to use buttons for calling the functions in HTML?

How to count average of values in the array?

Comment: Separately, please post only **one** question per question, not two.

Comment: In vanilla JavaScript (i.e. no libraries) or do you use e.g. jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Hello here is a working example. https://jsfiddle.net/7t41y80m/

HTML Example

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Array List</legend>
  <label id="lbl">1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9</label>
  <input type="number" id="input">
  <button onclick="AddNumber();">Add Number</button>
</fieldset>
<button onclick="CalculateAvg();">Print Averrage</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function CalculateAvg()
{
    const arr = document.getElementById('lbl').innerText.split(',').map(Number);
    const total = arr.reduce((x, y) => x + y, 0);
    const avg = total / arr.length || 0;
    alert(avg);
}

function AddNumber()
{
    document.getElementById('lbl').innerText += `,${document.getElementById('input').value}`;
}
```

Comment: Uncaught: ReferenceError: addNumber is not defined Uncaught: ReferenceError: printInfo is not defined

Comment: Uncaught: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null Uncaught: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null

Comment: i gave you a working jsfiddle..where did you get those messages

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of errors in your code.
First create the function outside of arr.push().
Second, you should call the function from somewhere for it to work. Also, next time provide the HTML too. You can see a working example here:

```js
let arr = [];

function addNumber() {
    const element = document.getElementById("num");
  const value = Number.isNaN(Number(element.value)) ? 0 :Number(element.value);
    arr.push(value)
    printInfo()
}

function printInfo() {
    console.log(`The array has ${arr.length} elements.`);
    const full = arr.reduce((acc, item) => (acc += item), 0)
    const average = full/arr.length

    console.log(`The average of the values is ${average}`)
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<button id='main' onclick="addNumber()">
Click me
</button>
<input id="num" type="number"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I am adding also a minimal working example in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5ybz6Lmk/

Comment: Incorrect output: your program printed "values", but should have printed "array"

Comment: program does not operate correctly.

Comment: The values in array are 2 The array has 1 elements Average is 2 The values in array are 2,7 The array has 2 elements Average is 4.5 The values in array are 2,7,10 The array has 3 elements Average is 6.333333333333333 The values in array are 2,7,10,25 The array has 4 elements Average is 11 The values in array are 2,7,10,25,12 The array has 5 elements Average is 11.2 The values in array are 2,7,10,25,12 The array has 5 elements Average is 11.2

Comment: I've added more output just to show you what you can achieve. I haven't tried to add the exact message, you can change it however you want. The average is calculated properly so just change a little the logic to do exactly what you need.
Also, this site doesn't exist for someone else to write your code but to help people struggling to find an answer to a problem.